# "Duke University Press" vs "Duke University Press Books"

Tags: citations

Which of these bibliography citations is preferred?:

> Weld, Kirsten. *Paper Cadavers: The Archives of Dictatorship in Guatemala.* Durham: Duke University Press, 2014.
>
> Weld, Kirsten. *Paper Cadavers: The Archives of Dictatorship in Guatemala.* Durham: Duke University Press Books, 2014.

Google shows both forms are in use for this particular book (and many like it). 
 In total, Google yields 442,000 results for "Durham: Duke University Press" and 14,200 results for "Durham: Duke University Press Books." Why are there two competing forms?

Comment: I suspect that these are just two of the accepted forms of citation for the publishing company.

Comment: Put whatever appears in the book.

Answer (score 3):

Their web site says [Duke University Press](https://www.dukeupress.edu/) (see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duke_University_Press)) and the copyright page from the [amazon.com "Look inside" option](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0822356023) says Duke University Press. Googling "Duke University Press Books" suggests to me that the addition of "Books" is extra, not part of the official name, such as saying "Dover Publishers Books" rather than "Dover Publishers". Thus, I think **Duke University Press** is what you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter. Pick one option and stick to it also when citing other books from Duke. I would go with the shorter and more frequently used version.